# Graph Automorphisms as permutation matrices of adjacency matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Graphs are often given by their "standard" definition through a set of nodes and a set of edges.

But for me, the adjacency matrix definition has always seemed more intuitive (and less cumbersome). It states that we're given an $N \times N$ matrix, A, such that $A_{i j} = 1 \iff i \sim j$. Otherwise, $A_{i j} = 0$. (Note this can be extended to weighted and directed graphs pretty easily).

If we are given two graphs, $A$ and $B$, an isomorphism between them is a permutation matrix $\sigma$ such that $\sigma A = B$ and $\sigma^{-1} B = A$. (equivalently, $\sigma$ is invertible)

But what would an automorphism of a graph, A, be? Is it a permutation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma A = A$? I don't think this can be correct, as the only $\sigma$ that would work is the identity matrix.

So how can automorphisms be described in the adjacency matrix definition of graphs?

Comment: You are almost correct. An isomorphism is $\sigma A\sigma^{-1} = B.$ It is a conjugation.

Comment: Oh, that makes a whole lot more sense now. My definition would imply that there is only one isomorphism between any two graphs, wouldn't it? Thanks.

Comment: The downside of the adjacency matrix definition is that it is unable to describe graphs whose vertex set is not the set of labels $1, 2,\dots, N$. For example, suppose you want to define the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph). With the standard approach, we can just say its vertex set consists of all $2$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, with an edge $xy$ whenever $x\cap y = \varnothing$. With an adjacency matrix, we first have to order these subsets before we can define $A_{ij}$; it becomes more cumbersome and less intuitive.